# Git permanent cache password

Tags: vim, git, tmux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is there a way to use `git config --global credential.helper` without a timeout? i.e. have it never ask for my password again?

Comment: Do you have an X11 session available in WSL, or are you running with the terminal only?

Comment: I can use X11 if that would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a credential helper on a permanent basis, there are a couple options you can use in WSL.  You can use the `store` credential helper, which will save your credentials in a file in your home directory.  Alternately, if you're running a desktop environment like GNOME or MATE, you can use the `libsecret` credential helper; however, this requires a full desktop environment, including DBus.

To use a new credential helper, you can do something like the following:

```
git config --global credential.helper store
```

You'll be prompted the first time for your credentials, and then they'll be saved and you won't be prompted again.

Note that the `libsecret` credential helper isn't built by default in Debian and Ubuntu; you'd need to build it yourself with something like the following:

```
cp -a /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret /tmp
cd /tmp/libsecret
make
cp git-credential-libsecret ~/bin # or somewhere else in your $PATH
```

It may also be possible to use the Windows credential helper by specifying its absolute path, depending on your environment.

Comment: Thanks so much @bk2004! I feel silly now. I had been using credential.helper cache instead of store and didn't realize that I could use store instead to make it perminent.